# How to validate tkinter entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm working on a tkinter app that has an entry widget and a method to validate it whenever the user types something in it. the problem is that the <Key> binding runs the validate method before `self.entry_str` is updated so it tests what was previously in the entry. what I want it to do is run the validate method after `self.entry_str` is updated, anyone know how I could do this? here's the simplified program:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        # StringVars
        self.error = tk.StringVar()
        self.error.set('')
        self.entry_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_str.set('')
        # widgets
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.entry_str)
        self.entry.bind('<Key>', lambda _: self.validate_entry())
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.error_label = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.error, fg='red')
        self.error_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.bttn = tk.Button(self.frame, text='continue', command=sys.exit)
        self.bttn.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def validate_entry(self):
        try:
            _ = int(self.entry_str.get())
        except ValueError:# entry is not valid: disable button and show error
            self.error.set('entry has to be an integer')
            self.bttn.config(state='disabled')
        else:# entry is valid: enable button and hide error
            self.error.set('')
            self.bttn.config(state='normal')


root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.wm_title('entry validation test')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<KeyRelease>` instead of `<Key>`

A better way would be to use `.trace`

```
self.entry_str = tk.StringVar()
self.entry_str.set('')
self.entry_str.trace('w', self.validate_entry)

...

def validate_entry(self, *event):
        try:
            _ = int(self.entry_str.get())
         ...
```

An alternative is to disable the user from entering anything but integer.

```
self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.entry_str, validate='key', validatecommand=(master.register(self.validate), "%P"))
...
def validate(self, char):  # this function must return only True or False
        return char.isdigit() or char==''
```

<sub>Do note `self.entry_str` will always be up-to date</sub>

Comment: How would the second method handle a Ctrl+V event?

Comment: @TheLizzard unless you have non-digit in the clipboard the paste operation will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. First one: save the entry data before the user inputs the data and restore the data if needed like this:

```py
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        # StringVars
        self.error = tk.StringVar()
        self.error.set('')
        self.entry_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_str.set('')
        # widgets
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.entry_str)
        self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.validate_entry)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.error_label = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.error, fg='red')
        self.error_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.bttn = tk.Button(self.frame, text='continue', command=sys.exit)
        self.bttn.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.current_entry_state = ""
        self.error_occured = False

    def validate_entry(self, event):
        current_entry_state = self.entry_str.get()
        # Save the state only if there are no invalid characters:
        try:
            _ = int(self.entry_str.get())
            self.current_entry_state = current_entry_state
            self.error_occured = False
        except:
            self.error_occured = True
        # Wait for tkinter to display the character
        self.entry.after(1, self._validate_entry)

    def _validate_entry(self):
        try:
            _ = int(self.entry_str.get())
        except ValueError:# entry is not valid: disable button and show error
            self.error.set('entry has to be an integer')
            # Restore the entry's text:
            self.entry.delete("0", "end")
            self.entry.insert("end", self.current_entry_state)
        else:
            if not self.error_occured:# entry is valid: enable button and hide error
                self.error.set('')


root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.wm_title('entry validation test')
root.mainloop()
```

There is another method (which isn't documented very well) but look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/11106801) and [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html).